# Laravel - Validate textinput value with database value

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application. In the project I want the users to set goals using these two tables:

```
class GoalType extends Model
{   
  protected $table = 'goal_types';
  protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'parent_id',
              'is_current',
              'max_score',
          ];

   public function children()
   {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\GoalType', 'parent_id');
   }

  public function goals()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Goal');
  }
}

class Goal extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'appraisal_goals';
  protected $fillable = [
              'goal_type_id',
              'employee_id',
              'weighted_score',
              'goal_description',
              'goal_title',
          ];

  public function goaltype()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\GoalType','goal_type_id');
  }  
}
```

As shown in the diagram below, GoalType is an hierarchical table. Only the parent have the max_score:

[image: goal type table]

Controller

```
public function create()
{
 $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
 $categories = GoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('goals.create')
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
public function store(StoreGoalRequest $request)
{
 $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $goal = new Goal();
    $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
    $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;
    $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
    $goal->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Goal is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('goals.index');
}
```

create.blade

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
         <div class="card card-secondary">
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
          <form  method="POST" action="{{route('goals.store')}}">
          @csrf
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option disabled="disabled" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                    @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endunless
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                  @endunless
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight:</label>
              <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  


       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('goals.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           
       
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
   </div>
   <!--/.col (left) -->
  </div>
```

[image: goals]

From the diagram above, GoalType (goal_type_id) dropdown contains all the children fields from goal_types. What I want to achieve is this:

1. When Goal Type is selected from the dropdown, the system goes to the goals table (Goal). It displays total weighted_score based on employee_id and goal_type_id.
2. When the user tries to enter data into weight text field (weighted_score), the application adds the value in the text field to the result in number one (1) above. If the result is more than the max_score in goal_types (GoalType) based on the parent max_score, then an error message is displayed.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX for this, if you're unfamiliar with it, you can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

I would also use JQuery to make things simpler. This way, you can do like this:

> 1. When Goal Type is selected from the dropdown, the system goes to the goals table (Goal). It displays total weighted_score based on employee_id and goal_type_id.

here you have to send to backend the goal type the user selected, for that, set an on change event in the combobox that triggers the AJAX request:

```
$('#goal_type').change(request_goals($('#goal_type').val()))
```

And the `request_goals` function should be like this:

```
function request_goals(){
    $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: /*YOUR CONTROLLER URL*/,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("error");
    },
    success: function (response) {
        /* HERE DO WHAT YOU NEED */
    }
}
```

You will have to create a route and a controller function that returns the data you need.

> When the user tries to enter data into weight text field (weighted_score), the application adds the value in the text field to the result in number one (1) above. If the result is more than the max_score in goal_types (GoalType) based on the parent max_score, then an error message is displayed.

Here you should do the same trick, set an event handler in the weighted_score field that sends an ajax request.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to archive it without AJAX calls, you can submit the form on select box change: `<select name="goal_type_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">`

In the controller you can catch the old input with `old("goal_type_id")`. You can query/calculate now the total weighted_score.

Comment: Can you kindly give an example based on my controller

Comment: I already did :-) Use can replace in your template `<select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">` with `<select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">`

And in your controllers `store()` method you put `dd(old('goal_type_id'))` so can can see the output and understand how to move on.

If you have more questions; let me know.